# Python 3 null terminated string to list?

Tags: python, string, binary, python-3.x, ascii

Python 3 really complicated the whole file reading process, when you have a binary file with some strings in it.

I can do `string.decode('ascii')` when I'm sure what I read is ascii text, but in my file I have strings with null `('\x00')` terminated strings I must read an convert to list of strings.
How would be the new way to do it, without going byte-by-byte and checking if it's a null or not?

```
mylist = chunkFromFile.split('\x00')

TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing that `chunkFromFile` is a `bytes` object. Then you also need to provide a `bytes` argument to the `.split()` method:

```
mylist = chunkFromFile.split(b'\x00')
```

See:

```
>>> chunkFromFile = bytes((123,45,0,67,89))
>>> chunkFromFile
b'{-\x00CY'
>>> chunkFromFile.split(b'\x00')
[b'{-', b'CY']
>>> chunkFromFile.split('\x00')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```